Overloads in python with pybind11 with sphinx documentation are different
I'm having some issues documenting python overloaded functions in sphinx when I'm using pybind11.
The following pybind code:
m.def("single_function", [&](int a, float b, std::vector<int>& c){

}, py::arg("a"), py::arg("b"), py::arg("c"), R"pbdoc(
    This function accepts an integer, a float, and a list of integers. 

    :param a: An integer parameter used for...
    :type a: int
    :param b: A floating-point parameter used for...
    :type b: float
    :param c: A list of integers, optional, default is empty.
    :type c: List[int]
    :return: None
    :rtype: None
)pbdoc");

which produces the following in the sphinx generated docs:

but the docs aren't quite as nice when I do overloaded functions e.g the following:
m.def("overloaded_function", [&](int d, float e, std::vector<int>& f){

}, py::arg("a"), py::arg("b"), py::arg("c"), R"pbdoc(
    This version accepts an integer, a float, and a list of integers.

    :param d: An integer parameter used for...
    :type d: int
    :param e: A floating-point parameter used for...
    :type e: float
    :param f: A list of integers, optional, default is empty.
    :type f: List[int]
    :return: None
    :rtype: None
)pbdoc");

m.def("overloaded_function", [&](double g){

}, py::arg("g"), R"pbdoc(
    This version accepts a single floating-point number.

    :param g: A floating-point parameter used for...
    :type g: float
    :return: None
    :rtype: None
)pbdoc");

produces the following in the sphinx docs:

as you can see we lose some of the nice formatting that the first function has.  It also loses clickable links when I use custom types for the parameters etc.
Is there a way to maintain the same level of formatting for overload functions?
my rst file is fairly simple:
.. automodule:: module
   :members:
   :imported-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :special-members:

and I'm using the sphinx_rtd_theme
